# In Wordpress, how do I only display a taxonomy if it has another taxonomy on it?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I'm working on a custom Wordpress site that was built for us by consultants.  The current logic loops through and displays all of the Media Library tags and works well.  However we would like to update that logic to *only* display the Media Library tag IF it has another category tied to it (if a category is passed via a url parameter).

**Example:**

resources-tag - options:

Brochures, Case Studies, Data Sheets, etc.

resources-categories - options:

Apple-Mac, Google, Cloud, Education, Finance, etc.

Current code:

```
  $category=$type='';
  $args=$arrCat=$arrTag=array();
  $type= $_POST['type'];
  $category=esc_attr( $_POST['category']);
    //$sorting=esc_attr( $_POST['sorting']);
 
  if($type):
    $tags = (object) array(get_term_by('slug', $type, 'resources-tag'));
  else:
    $tags = get_terms( array(
      'taxonomy' => 'resources-tag',
      'hide_empty' => false,
      'orderby' => 'front_display_priority',
      'order' => 'ASC',
      ) ); 
  endif;
  if ($tags) :
    foreach ($tags as $term):

    // HTML and some php here to display the tags
```

This particular page won't always have a category, but when it does, the logic should check to see if what resources-tags are in those results and then iterate those.

So if the url param has a category of "Google" and the only media library types that have that category are Brochures and Data Sheets, those are the only ones that should show up.

Please advise.  Thank you.

Comment: I don't really understand what you are specifically trying to do, but maybe [`get_post_taxonomies`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_taxonomies/), [`get_object_taxonomies`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_object_taxonomies/), [`get_attachment_taxonomies`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_attachment_taxonomies/) and [`wp_get_post_terms`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_post_terms/) could help?

Answer (score 0):

So I was able to figure this out after only having banged my head against the wall for a few hours.

This is what I did:

```
  $post_per_page = get_field('media_post_per_page', 'option')?get_field('media_post_per_page', 'option'):3;
  $args=array('post_type'=>'media_resources','posts_per_page'=>$post_per_page,'post_status' =>'publish','paged' => $paged);
    $someposts = get_posts(
    array(
        'post_type' => 'media_resources',
        'posts_per_page' => $post_per_page,
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'fields' => 'ids', // return an array of ids
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'resources-category',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => $category,
            )
        )
    )
);

    $tags = get_terms(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'resources-tag',
            'hide_empty' => 1,
            'object_ids' => $someposts,
        )
    );
```

I found it here: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/WP_Term_Query/__construct/

Thanks @bucketpress !